# How do I search nested lists for an element and return a single statement if the element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a list of lists containing characteristics of food.

What I want to be able to do is search take input from the user for the name of the food and then:
IF the food is in the list, print details about the food
IF the food is NOT in the list, print a single line to advise the food is not found

I have managed to create use a for loop to iterate over the list and return details of the food if the food is found.
What I am struggling to do is return a SINGLE line to say 'Food not found' if the food is not in the lists.

I have tried a while loop to basically say 'while the food is not found, tell the user and ask for input again' but this hasnt worked
I have tried 'if food is not in the list' print out the statement but that either seems to print the same line for as many iterations as the food is not found OR it prints the line even if the food is in the list.

Here is the code:

```
#initialising list 
food_list = ['banana', 10, 'f', 'yellow'], ['apple', 12, 'f', 'red'], ['pear', 60, 'f', 'green'], ['mango', 5, 'f', 'yellow'], ['lettuce', 3, 'v', 'green'], ['beans', 20, 'v', 'green'], ['red capsicum', 1, 'v', 'red'], ['corn', 20, 'v', 'yellow']
#requesting input to determine which food to look for
name = input('What food are you looking for? ')

#iterable loop to search through nested lists
for food in food_list:
    if name in food:
            if food[2] == 'f':
                print(f'All about', food[0], '--> FRUIT')
                print()
                print(f'Name:', food[0])
                print()
                print(f'Colour: ', food[3])
                print()
                print(f'Total available: {food[1]}')
            elif food[2] == 'v':
                print(f'All about', food[0], '--> VEGETABLE')
                print()
                print(f'Name:', food[0])
                print()
                print(f'Colour: ', food[3])
                print()
                print(f'Total available: {food[1]}'
```

The above works to find the food and print details.
The below has not worked when trying to return a line to say a food isnt found.

```
#initialising list 
food_list = ['banana', 10, 'f', 'yellow'], ['apple', 12, 'f', 'red'], ['pear', 60, 'f', 'green'], ['mango', 5, 'f', 'yellow'], ['lettuce', 3, 'v', 'green'], ['beans', 20, 'v', 'green'], ['red capsicum', 1, 'v', 'red'], ['corn', 20, 'v', 'yellow']
#requesting input to determine which food to look for
name = input('What food are you looking for? ')
while name not in food_list:
    print('Sorry not found')
    name = input('What fruit are you looking for? ')
```

)

```
#initialising list 
food_list = ['banana', 10, 'f', 'yellow'], ['apple', 12, 'f', 'red'], ['pear', 60, 'f', 'green'], ['mango', 5, 'f', 'yellow'], ['lettuce', 3, 'v', 'green'], ['beans', 20, 'v', 'green'], ['red capsicum', 1, 'v', 'red'], ['corn', 20, 'v', 'yellow']
#requesting input to determine which food to look for
name = input('What food are you looking for? ')
for food in food_list:
    if name not in food:
        print('Sorry not here')
    elif name in food:
            if food[2] == 'f':
                print(f'All about', food[0], '--> FRUIT')
                print()
                print(f'Name:', food[0])
                print()
                print(f'Colour: ', food[3])
                print()
                print(f'Total available: {food[1]}')
            elif food[2] == 'v':
                print(f'All about', food[0], '--> VEGETABLE')
                print()
                print(f'Name:', food[0])
                print()
                print(f'Colour: ', food[3])
                print()
                print(f'Total available: {food[1]}')
```

Comment: why not use a json string and then search json the tree for a match?

Comment: Slight nitpick: `food_list` is a _tuple_ of lists, not a list of lists. Even though it doesn't really affect anything, it's good to know what type your variables are, just so you don't try something like `food_list.append(...)` later.

Comment: Thank you @PranavHosangadi - it's a great pick up because I actually want the lists to be mutable! So I might need to figure out how to change that. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jo "how to change that": when you define a variable as `x = 1, 2, 3`, python understands it to be a tuple. To make it a list, just add brackets: `x = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Appreciate it @PranavHosangadi - you’ve been very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to implement the behavior you want. Here's one.

```
#iterable loop to search through nested lists
index = -1
for n,food in enumerate(food_list):
    if name in food:
        index = n

if index == -1:
    print('Sorry not found')
else:
    food = food_list[index]
    if food[2] == 'f':
        print(f'All about', food[0], '--> FRUIT')
        print()
    elif food[2] == 'v':
        print(f'All about', food[0], '--> VEGETABLE')
        print()
    print(f'Name:', food[0])
    print()
    print(f'Colour: ', food[3])
    print()
    print(f'Total available: {food[1]}')
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked a treat. It hadn't occurred to me to use an index. You've also introduced me to enumerate() so that is next on my list to better understand and start using. Appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks also for helping to simplify the code by printing the last 5 lines only once! :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest building a dict keyed by names, so you can simply do `name in food_dict` to see if you have food by that name.

```
food_dict = {f[0]: f for f in food_list}  # {name: food}
food_types = {
    'f': "FRUIT",
    'v': "VEGETABLE",
}

while True:
    name = input('What food are you looking for? ')
    if name in food_dict:
        break
    print("Sorry, not found!")

[name, qty, ftype, color] = food_dict[name]
print(f"All about {name} --> {food_types[ftype]}\n")
print(f"Name: {name}\n")
print(f"Colour: {color}\n")
print(f"Total available: {qty}")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven’t learned about dict yet so will look this up. 
Is there any way to avoid the break statement as I need to find a way to do this without the use of break or continue.

Comment: Yes, but that's a condition you didn't include in your original question (and I don't know that any alternative I suggest won't fall afoul of some similar condition) so I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader rather than trying to play 20 questions.  :)

Comment: That's fair enough @Samwise - I do appreciate your help. I'll have a play around. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a flag that is updated when the food is found then after the loop you check if the flag value has changed.  If it doesn't, it means that you don't found the food so you print the statement.

```py
#initialising list 
food_list = ['banana', 10, 'f', 'yellow'], ['apple', 12, 'f', 'red'], ['pear', 60, 'f', 'green'], ['mango', 5, 'f', 'yellow'], ['lettuce', 3, 'v', 'green'], ['beans', 20, 'v', 'green'], ['red capsicum', 1, 'v', 'red'], ['corn', 20, 'v', 'yellow']
#requesting input to determine which food to look for
name = input('What food are you looking for? ')

# FLAG INITIALIZATION
flag = True

#iterable loop to search through nested lists
for food in food_list:
    if name in food:
            flag = False # HERE YOU CHANGE THE STATE OF THE FLAG
            if food[2] == 'f':
                print(f'All about', food[0], '--> FRUIT')
                print()
                print(f'Name:', food[0])
                print()
                print(f'Colour: ', food[3])
                print()
                print(f'Total available: {food[1]}')
            elif food[2] == 'v':
                print(f'All about', food[0], '--> VEGETABLE')
                print()
                print(f'Name:', food[0])
                print()
                print(f'Colour: ', food[3])
                print()
                print(f'Total available: {food[1]}')


# CHECK THE FLAG VALUE
if flag:
    print("Food Not Found")
```

Just to mention, using `dict` structure is way useful to manage this kind of data